# Using a variable in wx.Frame in wx.Panel

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, wxpython, python-imaging-library

I have created an application that is split into two parts; the left is the frame which has sliders that I want the values to be used to modify the right panel.

Here is the code:

```
import wx
import numpy 
import matplotlib
import random
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import Image
import ImageEnhance

#from wx.lib.pubsub import pub 

class Main(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(1200,800))
        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.varPanel = wx.Panel(self.sp, style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
        self.imgPanel = ImgPanel(self.sp)
        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.varPanel,self.imgPanel,300)
        self.conSlider = wx.Slider(self.varPanel, -1, 0, 1, 10, pos=(10,10), size=(250,-1), style=wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.sliderUpdate)
        self.Show(True)

    def sliderUpdate(self, event):
        self.conValue = self.conSlider.GetValue()
        #print "Contrast: ", self.conValue
        return self.conValue
        #pub.sendMessage("panelListener", message=self.conValue)
```

---

```
class ImgPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):     
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,-1,size=(50,50))

        #pub.subscribe(self.myListener, "panelListener")

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)

        self.drawImg()

    '''def myListener(self, message, arg2=None):
        """
        Listener function
        """
        return message'''

    def contrast(self, img, value):
        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
        conImg = enhancer.enhance(value)
        return conImg

    def drawImg(self):

        img = Image.open("d50.tif").convert("L")

        #cIm = self.contrast(img, random.uniform(0, 3))
        #cIm = self.contrast(img, message)
        cIm = self.contrast(img, self.conValue) # how to get slider value?? 

        arr = numpy.array(cIm) 
        im  = plt.imshow(arr, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Main("Title")
    app.MainLoop()
```

I want the value of my slider in the frame to be passed down to the drawImg() method in the panel. I was under the impression this was possible because the frame is parent to the panel. However, when run I get an attribute not found error for conValue.

I tried using messages as described here http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/ but without any luck (my code trying this has been commented out)

Please could someone help explain what I have done wrong and how I can use the slider variable in my panel.

-----Edit-----

New code based on Sundars help:

```
import wx
import numpy 
import matplotlib
import random
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import Image
import ImageEnhance

#from wx.lib.pubsub import pub 

class Main(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(1200,800))

        self.conValue=''
        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.varPanel = wx.Panel(self.sp, style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
        self.imgPanel = ImgPanel(self, self.sp)
        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.varPanel,self.imgPanel,300)
        self.conSlider = wx.Slider(self.varPanel, -1, 0, 1, 10, pos=(10,10), size=(250,-1), style=wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.sliderUpdate)
        self.Show(True)
        self.conValue = ""

    def sliderUpdate(self, event):
        self.conValue = self.conSlider.GetValue()
        #print "Contrast: ", self.conValue
        return self.conValue
        #pub.sendMessage("panelListener", message=self.conValue)
```

---

```
class ImgPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, frameclass, parent):     
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,-1,size=(50,50))
        self.frameclass=frameclass
        #pub.subscribe(self.myListener, "panelListener")
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)

        self.drawImg()

    '''def myListener(self, message, arg2=None):
        """
        Listener function
        """
        return message'''

    def contrast(self, img, value):
        '''
        Method to alter the contrast of an image. 
        A factor of 0.0 gives a solid grey image. A factor of 1.0 gives the original image.
        Returns the altered image.
        '''
        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
        conImg = enhancer.enhance(value)
        return conImg

    def drawImg(self):

        img = Image.open("d50.tif").convert("L")

        #cIm = self.contrast(img, random.uniform(0, 3)) # contrast change 
        #cIm = self.contrast(img, message)
        cIm = self.contrast(img, self.frameclass.conValue)

        arr = numpy.array(cIm) 
        im  = plt.imshow(arr, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Main("Title")
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am now receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\VSEM\VSEM\module2.
py", line 78, in <module>
    frame = Main("Title")
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\VSEM\VSEM\module2.
py", line 21, in __init__
    self.imgPanel = ImgPanel(self, self.sp)
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\VSEM\VSEM\module2.
py", line 47, in __init__
    self.drawImg()
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\VSEM\VSEM\module2.
py", line 71, in drawImg
    cIm = self.contrast(img, self.frameclass.conValue)
  File "C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\VSEM\VSEM\module2.
py", line 62, in contrast
    conImg = enhancer.enhance(value)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageEnhance.py", line 36, in enhance
    return Image.blend(self.degenerate, self.image, factor)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2008, in blend
    return im1._new(core.blend(im1.im, im2.im, alpha))
TypeError: a float is required
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: you should inalize the self.conA in init function say self.conA="".

Comment: and also pass the frame object to two class. they have parent of splitting window but not the frame

Comment: Hi Sundar. Thanks for your comment but I don't quite follow. What do you mean pass the frame to both classes? How is this done?

Comment: hi nate have you tried my answer

Comment: Hi Sundar, yes I have tried your answer but have received a type error as described below.

Comment: Did you change  image class init def __init__(self, parent):  todef __init__(self,frameclass, parent):

Comment: sorry i forget about that please change image class init not the parent init

Comment: yes, I added everything exactly as shown in your answer.

Comment: still you get the error ? please share what you tried by editing your questin replace with what you tried

Comment: I have just seen your change. Now I am receiving `TypeError: a float is required` when trying to pass the slider value to the PIL method

Comment: then who should figure out what type of value need to send. i have helped to acess the variable then try using float(value ) in the method

Comment: try using float(value) in contrast method

Comment: Understood. I think the problem was it was recieving a string due to `self.conValue=''` so I changed that to `self.conValue=float()` and seem to have something to work with.

Comment: no no.when your getting the value please convert it with float. and in method constract please validate that is value is empty or not

Comment: if accessing the variable help you please dont forget to accept the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer

Comment: When converting to float in the method with `float(value)` I get a `ValueError: could not convert string to float`

Comment: yes you need to know what are you sending.try print the value before you use in method so that you will find .please share the what is value in value

Comment: Ok, so it appears that when it first runs value is nothing with type string as per `self.conValue=''`. What is being passed from conValue is an int. So now I have to work out how to initially have it run with a float or int and then update as value changes.

Comment: yes! Correct work on that you will get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing :

in Frame class inside init create the variable

```
self.conValue=''
```

next,while calling imagepanel pass the Frame class also

```
self.imgPanel = ImgPanel(self,self.sp)
```

next inside init of image class

```
class ImgPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self,frameclass, parent): 

       self.frameclass=frameclass
```

now,you can call it as

```
cIm = self.contrast(img, self.frameclass.conValue)
```

Comment: I have added what you have suggested however a "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)" when calling self.imgPanel = ImgPanel(self, self.sp)